# Accessing inbound property in mule

Tags: mule

In this sub-flow, how can I access from the http connector (red area) the inbound properties available at green marked area.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it would be different. You can access the inbound properties the same way you would on green area and on red area. After the red area however, the inbound properties will not contain a different set as a result of that HTTP request.

Comment: Completely agree with @tyrone ... What is the issue you are facing ?? update your flow with your config and your exception if any

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tyrone and Anirban, additionally how can I ensure the Content-Type inbound-property that exists at green marked area is propagated into an HTTP header after crossing red marked area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of the inbound property is only just after the inbound endpoint or the source endpoint.

Here you should copy your inbound properties to the "flowVars" and then use it across the flow

```
#[flowVars.paramerterName = message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.parameterName]
```

Comment: Additionally how can I ensure the Content-Type inbound-property that exists at green marked area is propagated into an HTTP header after crossing red marked area?

Comment: Have a logger before the green box and try printing there and you will not have the inbound properties there.

Comment: But I have to make sure that the inbound property should be available after the red marked area. What can I do ?                                                   1. To Write the inbound property into the message payload.
2. Copy the inbound property into an outbound property.
3. Write the inbound property into an attachment.
4. No change is necessary, inbound properties will propagate as headers by default.

Comment: As said in my answer you need to copy all your inbound properties to every flowVars and then you need to copy values from FlowVars to the outbound properties

Comment: Let me know if I should elaborate more in my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Please make note if you want to access the HTTP properties, the syntax MEL format will be different for the Mule latest version and old version. The above one is valid for the latest Mule version and the syntax to access any property like below

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.cityname]
```

where as in previous versions

```
#[message.inboundProperties['propertyName']].
```

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your inbound message source, but assuming it is an HTTP connector, use the MEL expression to access the inbound property http.query.params

#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']

The inbound message object is nothing but a HashMap of key-value pairs - best would be to use the debugger and select the keys you would like to access.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation for the Mule message](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-fundamentals/v/3.7/mule-message-structure), there you will find the description for the different kind of variables and properties. Inbound properties should be propagated from the main flow to the sub-flow and should still be available after the choice, excepting the case where you overwrite them or when there is an outbound-endpoint, which would overwrite them too.